# Dealing with API routes in form of interfaces

Tags: go

Today I had an interesting idea. I have been copy/pasting the following line for each kind of request method for every route.

```
http.Handle("/api/my/custom/route", mw.Chain(api.PostFunc, mw.Method("POST"), mw.Logging()))
```

It struck me that it looked very bad and unprofessional so I came up with a new idea.

```
type RouteInstructor struct {
    Instance struct {
        URL  string
        Data struct {
            Method   string
            Callback string
        }
    }
}

func Routes() {
    routes := &RouteInstructor{
        Instance: map[string]interface{}{
            URL: "/api/my/custom/route",
            Data: map[string]interface{}{
                Method:   "POST",
                Callback: api.PostFunc,
            },

            Data: map[string]interface{}{
                Method:   "GET",
                Callback: api.GetFunc,
            },
        },
    }

    mw.Routes(routes)
}
```

Instead of calling the `mw.Chain` method and `http.Handle`, wouldn't it be better to make a struct, pass it to a middleware method where you apply `mw.Chain` and everything else? Although it does become more code, I feel like it becomes easier to understand and therefore more effective.

What do you think of this new way of mine? What are pros and the cons?

Comment: You'll need to provide code that works before asking for a review (see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). From what I see, your code wouldn't compile and it's not clear what mw is or whether mw.Routes() is already implemented. If you can clarify those points, I'm sure you can expect helpful reviews of your code and ideas :)